# How to fill a specified area using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

I want to fill some regions which are only parts of a shape in a TikZ drawing (marked as "Here" in the following drawings):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,calc,arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[axis/.style={very thick, ->, >=stealth'}]
    % axis
        \draw[axis] (9,2.5)  -- (13.5,2.5) node(xline)[right]
            {$x_N$};
        \draw[axis] (11.25,0.5) -- (11.25,4.5) node(yline)[above] {$\hat{x}_N$};
         
    \draw[->, ultra thick](7,2.5) -- (8.5,2.5);    
    \draw [very thick] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(2,4) (5,3) (2,0.5) (1,1.75) (1,4) };
    %\draw[very thick] (0.5,3) to [ curve through ={(5.5,2) . . ( 3,0.25) . . (1,0.25) }]( 0.5,3 ) ;
    
    \draw[dashed, very thick] (11.25,2.5) ellipse (1cm and 1.5cm);
    \draw[dashed, very thick] (5,3) ellipse (1.5cm and 1cm);
    \draw[step=0.25cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (15,5);
    \node (a) at (4,3) {Here};
    \node (b) at (11.7,3) {Here};
    \node (a) at (11.7,2) {Here};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I don't really get what the question is about? Is it about filling dashed areas (which is not a real problem as you can fill dashed areas like any other area) or is it about how to fill only the areas marked with "here", which means filling only parts of a shape? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Is it about how to fill only the areas marked with "here", which means filling only parts of a shape.

Comment: You want to fill the _intersection_ of two shapes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you seek? Here `scope` environment is used. Be aware that `clip` command must be contained in the `scope` environment to limit the effect of clipping. Without `scope` environment, the clipping effect will continue to the end of the code.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,calc,arrows,patterns}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[axis/.style={very thick, ->, >=stealth'}]
    % axis
        \draw[axis] (9,2.5)  -- (13.5,2.5) node(xline)[right]
            {$x_N$};
        \draw[axis] (11.25,0.5) -- (11.25,4.5) node(yline)[above] {$\hat{x}_N$};
    \draw[->, ultra thick](7,2.5) -- (8.5,2.5);  
\begin{scope}
\draw [very thick] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(2,4) (5,3) (2,0.5) (1,1.75) (1,4) }; 
\clip (5,3) ellipse (1.5cm and 1cm);
 \draw [fill=red,very thick] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(2,4) (5,3) (2,0.5) (1,1.75) (1,4) };
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\draw [dashed,very thick] (11.25,2.5) ellipse (1cm and 1.5cm);
\clip (11.25,2.5) ellipse (1cm and 1.5cm);
\fill [red] (11.25,0) rectangle (15,5);
\end{scope}
    \draw[dashed, very thick] (5,3) ellipse (1.5cm and 1cm);
    \draw[step=0.25cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (15,5);
    \node (a) at (4,3) {Here};
    \node (b) at (11.7,3) {Here};
    \node (a) at (11.7,2) {Here};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** With `patterns` from tikzlibrary, and put `pattern=crosshatch dots` in the `fill/draw` options, one gets

[image]

Comment: Yes. But, I would like to use crosshatch dots for example instead of the red color. I tried with \fill [pattern=crosshatch dots] (11.25,0) rectangle (15,5); but it does not produce pdf file (there was an error)...

Comment: Hi, did you include the \usetikzlibrary{patterns}? I just tried and still worked.

Comment: If I use \tikzlibrary{patterns}, it says "undefined control sequance" but when replacing it with \usetikzlibrary{patterns} there were no pdf produced (unknown error)...

Comment: I copied and pasted my answer and re-run again, yielding the expected crosshatch dots output. Please remove all aux files and retry again.

Comment: This woks fine in a single test document but it fails when used in my whole document (a thesis). I will post a part of the message Error: 
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
Current file position is 19980114
GPL Ghostscript 9.07: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
### FAILED to generate /tmp/altpdflatex.3426-1387293090/these.pdf ()

Comment: I think I should use pstrick instead of Tikz. By the way, how we do this with pstrick? (all the components of the figure still the same except the object obtained by "\draw [very thick] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(2,4) (5,3) (2,0.5) (1,1.75) (1,4) };" wich can be replaced by a closed Bezier curve for example)...

Comment: Hi, It is justifable that you post a new question focusing on pstrick. There are specislists who can give you directions. Be sure your MWE covers what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using the nonzero rule and the even odd rule to fill paths. All I did was adapt your code with these commands. It can be done cleaner. In addition, you should use scope to group items.

This example is mainly to show what can be done with the nonzero and the even odd rules.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,calc,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[axis/.style={very thick, ->, >=stealth'}]

%note the inversion of the plot points. This is to make the nonzero rule
%work properly on this path    
\fill [nonzero rule,blue,postaction={even odd rule,fill=white}]
         plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(1,4)(1,1.75)(2,0.5)(5,3)(2,4)}
         (5,3) ellipse (1.5cm and 1cm);

\draw [blue,very thick] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(2,4) (5,3) (2,0.5) (1,1.75) (1,4) };
\draw[red,dashed, very thick] (5,3) ellipse (1.5cm and 1cm);
\fill[gray] (11.25,2.5) ellipse (1cm and 1.5cm);


\fill[even odd rule,white]
        (11.25,2.5) ellipse (1cm and 1.5cm)
        (11.25,0.5) rectangle (13.25,4.5);
    \draw[dashed, very thick] (11.25,2.5) ellipse (1cm and 1.5cm);

\draw[->, ultra thick](7,2.5) -- (8.5,2.5);    

% axis
    \draw[axis] (9,2.5)  -- (13.5,2.5) node(xline)[right]
        {$x_N$};
    \draw[axis] (11.25,0.5) -- (11.25,4.5) node(yline)[above] {$\hat{x}_N$};


\draw[step=0.25cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (15,5);
\node (a) at (4,3) {Here};
\node (b) at (11.7,3) {Here};
\node (a) at (11.7,2) {Here};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]